# Best practice for launching many instances using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, boto3

[image]

Let's assume I want to launch a small task a large number of times (>30k).

I know how to programmatically create an instance, run a script on that instance using `from boto.manage.cmdshell import sshclient_from_instance` and I know how to terminate that instance using `ec2_res.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[new_instance[0].id]).terminate()`.

Now the question is what exactly is best practice if I want to launch this task a number of times and have them run in parallel.

I want to distribute a simple task broadly yet not leave a huge number of instances sitting out there.

Do I:

- Create a large number of instances and give them a "tag" and then delete instances by way of this tag later?
- Leverage python's multiprocessing and launch each "instance" management in its own thread where I (1) create the instance (2) run the stuff (3) terminate the instance?
- something else I am not thinning of

What is best practice for something like this?

This task (I assume) is non-unique to aws.